# Best Practices for building JavaScript libraries inside larger web applications

Tags: javascript, asp.net, github, web-applications

I'm building a web application using ASP.NET MVC, and I'm building a few JavaScript libraries that I want to host on GitHub.

My current workflow for updating the JavaScript libraries are:

- Make changes to the JavaScript libraries in my web app
- Test the changes by launching the web app
- Copy those changes to my GitHub repos

Is there a better way to automatically deploy the changes without having to copy/paste?

Comment: Visual Studio has Git integration. Why not just push to your repos from there?

Comment: Visual Studio does have Git intigration. The terminology is somewhat different though. Are your libraries in GitHub source control? Can you clone the repository and do a git commit/push after you have made your changes.

Comment: Can I select a folder and only have that and its sub folders/files in one git repo, while the parent folder (the project folder) points to a secondary repo?  Will I be able to still commit that subfolder and its contents to the main project repo? Sorry, my git is still weak.